# i am trying to remote mount filesystem on centos 7

Tags: centos7, mount

Below is my CLI snippet.

i am trying to remote mount filesystem but i have created remotecluster and remotefs i get this remotecluster:

[root@gpfs1 ~]# mmremotecluster show

Cluster name:    gpfs2

Contact nodes:   gpfs2

SHA digest:      c413d960c10b7628940fb65b0238ccf2d4571cd4d0877616659a17876848df8d

File systems:    gpfs_servers_cluster1 (gpfs_servers_cluster)

remotefilesystem:

[root@gpfs1 ~]# mmremotefs show

Local Name  Remote Name  Cluster name       Mount Point        Mount Options    Automount  Drive  Priority
gpfs_servers_cluster1 gpfs_servers_cluster gpfs2              /gpfs/storage1     rw               no           -        0

but i try to mount file system i get this error:

[root@gpfs1 ~]# mmmount all

Fri Dec  6 16:39:45 IST 2019: mmmount: Mounting file systems ...

mount: mount gpfs_servers_cluster1 on /gpfs/storage1 failed: Stale file handle.

Comment: This question as off-topic because it is not related to programming as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is more suited on another Stack Exchange site: [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). Please read their own [help pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create disk below the steps:

1) sdb : dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdb count=10240 bs=64k

sdc : dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdc count=10240 bs=64k

2) need to create vim stanza.nsds file

%nsd: device=/sdb

nsd=nsd3

servers=gpfs2

usage=dataOnly

failureGroup=100

pool=data

%nsd: device=/sdc

nsd=nsd4

servers=gpfs2

usage=dataOnly

failureGroup=100

pool=data

3) after that create disk :

mmcrnsd -F stanza.nsds -v no

3) mmlsnsd

File system Disk name NSD servers

(free disk) nsd3 gpfs2
(free disk) nsd4 gpfs2

4) create file system and mount point.